# Como imperdir conexão de parar a aplicação?

Tags: android

Tenho uma aplicação Android que envia dados para um servidor através de wireless, ao enviar muda da Atividade B para a A.

Acontece que quando a conexão é fraca a aplicação para e dá o erro abaixo.

Pelo que entendi do que li no SOen isso acontece porque ao bloquear a minha Atividade B perdem-se dados essenciais que seriam passados de Atividade B para a A e dai o erro.

Alguém me sabe dizer uma forma de resolver isto?

**PS: O processo tem de ser síncrono.**

Log do erro:

> 09-30 14:47:22.999: E/Parcel(577): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.exemplo.objectos.meuObjeto 09-30 14:47:22.999: E/Parcel(577):     at
>   java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 09-30 14:47:22.999:
>   E/Parcel(577):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251) 09-30
>   14:47:22.999: E/Parcel(577):  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216) 09-30 14:47:22.999:
>   E/Parcel(577):    at
>   android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2140) 09-30
>   14:47:22.999: E/Parcel(577):  at
>   android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2104) 09-30 14:47:22.999:
>   E/Parcel(577):    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2020) 09-30
>   14:47:22.999: E/Parcel(577):  at
>   android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2321) 09-30
>   14:47:22.999: E/Parcel(577):  at
>   android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249) 09-30 14:47:22.999:
>   E/Parcel(577):    at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1118) 09-30
>   14:47:22.999: E/Parcel(577):  at
>   android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:5145) 09-30
>   14:47:22.999: E/Parcel(577):  at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1466)
>   09-30 14:47:22.999: E/Parcel(577):    at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1061)
>   09-30 14:47:22.999: E/Parcel(577):    at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:4067)
>   09-30 14:47:22.999: E/Parcel(577):    at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:3965)
>   09-30 14:47:22.999: E/Parcel(577):    at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:159)
>   09-30 14:47:22.999: E/Parcel(577):    at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2646)
>   09-30 14:47:22.999: E/Parcel(577):    at
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404) 09-30 14:47:22.999:
>   E/Parcel(577):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method) 09-30
>   14:47:22.999: E/Parcel(577): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/exemplo/objectos/meuObjeto 09-30
>   14:47:22.999: E/Parcel(577):  ... 18 more 09-30 14:47:22.999:
>   E/Parcel(577): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't
>   find class "com.exemplo.objectos.meuObjeto" on path:
>   DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]] 09-30 14:47:22.999: E/Parcel(577):  at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   09-30 14:47:22.999: E/Parcel(577):    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497) 09-30
>   14:47:22.999: E/Parcel(577):  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)

Comment: Põe um `catch Exception` :P :D

Comment: @bigown seu mau :P

Comment: Isso é pouco para poder ajudar-te. Terás de dar mais elementos.

Comment: @ramaral estou a tentar reproduzir. Quando tiver mais coloco.

Comment: @ramaral já tem ai o log.

Comment: O erro aconteceu nas mesmas circunstâncias que descrevestes na pergunta? Sabes o que é `com.sdilab.objectos.meuObjeto`?

Comment: @ramaral sim é um objeto que eu uso numa lista na atividade A

Comment: @ramaral alias é o objeto selecionado em A depois vai a B fazer umas alterações, depois ao fazer enviar para o servidor a aplicação volta para A com o objeto acopulado.

Comment: Pela edição à pergunta suponho que agora o erro surgiu noutra situação. Consegues descrevê-la? Ia perguntar se esse objecto era passado para a outra Activity mas já respondeste. Como é um erro que só acontece de vez em quando  não será fácil de resolver sem saber em que circunstâncias acontece.

Comment: A situação é a mesma @ramaral eu é que não soube explicar bem quando criei a pergunta. Só acontece as vezes, sim quando a rede é fraca, isto porque eu tenho dois estados na app, offline e online e corre tudo bem. O problema aparece quando o sinal da rede é muito fraco.

Comment: @ramaral mas no cliente acontece com frequência. Já tentei que ele me mandasse o log dele, mas o que ele me mandou não tinha erro nenhum.

Comment: @ramaral esqueci-me de referir eu tenho uma biblioteca externa que me faz os envios ao servidor, eu só espero o resultado dela e continuo a execução da minha app.

Comment: Você pode colocar a parte do código que faz/trata essa requisição?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma.
Crie um Service para enviar seus arquivos, o service executa em background. Enquanto o Service estiver enviando os dados você pode exibir um ProgressDialog. Quando o envio terminar de ser feito basta apenas informar a activity principal para fechar o progress e passar para a próxima activity.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta mas tem de ser síncrono o processo.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve executar este processo de conexão com o servidor dentro de uma `AsyncTask`, pois caso demore a conexão está rodando dentro de outra Thread e não na principal.

Exemplo:

Crie uma classe que extende de `AsyncTask`, e dentro do doInBackground você faz todo o processo pesado.

```
 class MeuAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{  
      @Override  
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {  

           // aqui você executa o seu processo de conexão com o servidor.

           return null;  
      }  
 }
```

e para executar você deve fazer o seguinte código:

```
MeuAsyncTask meuAsync = new MeuAsyncTask();
meuAsync.execute();
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta mas tem de ser síncrono o processo.

Answer (score 0):

Você forneceu poucos detalhes e insiste numa solução síncrona. Boa parte dos recursos do Android, assim como outros sistemas operacionais, funciona com threads, que rodam de maneira independente e assíncrona.

Não acredito que você irá conseguir realizar essa conexão de maneira totalmente  síncrona, mas o que você pode fazer é simular um comportamento síncrono. Penso em duas maneiras de fazer isso:

- disparar uma thread e monitorar até ela ser completada; você pode fazer isso dentro de um loop, mas isso consome recursos e não é a maneira mais adequada.
- disparar uma thread e configurar um callback, um método que será executado quando ela for concluída e sinalizará que a execução pode continuar.